# "Where you'd like to work" is unclear, should be split into two fields

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On my job status, I'm prompted to enter "where [I]'d like to work". So I entered a city I'd like to work in:

[image: Where you'd like to work]

It then shows up as "Willing to relocate to [city]".

[image: Willing to relocate to]

That's not what I entered, that means something very different, and in my case it happens to not be true. The city I entered is a city that's close enough for me for a daily commute, not a city I'd even consider moving to.

Can we get two separate entry fields, one for "Willing to work from", and another "Willing to relocate to"?

Comment: It would make more sense for the UI to just be consistent. When I tell it where I'd like to work, it should display that as the place(s) I'd like to work, not silently transform it into something different. I can't really see the benefit in having two separate entry fields. One seems sufficient. All the employer really cares about is where you are willing to work, not if you plan to commute or move there. (Remote commuting is handled elsewhere.)

Comment: @CodyGray That'd be fine with me too, but I do know some employers do care at least a bit, for example because of the time it would take to show up in case of an emergency, even if it would hopefully never be needed.

Comment: Willing to relocate is from the point of view of the employer.  And you are willing to relocate to that location (for work).  That you won't live in that city is of no concern to an employer.  They won't mandate where you live.

Comment: @dave That's not what "relocate" means.

Comment: @hvd: ahhh, I just realised your problem, since you aren't going to move home there are no relocation costs involved for the employer should you take a position in city X even though you currently live in city Y (and are willing to commute).

Comment: @hvd Can you add a screen shot or two?

Comment: @Ana Is this good enough?

Comment: I'd *like* a tall glass of Firestone Walker's Parabola. I'm *willing* to drink Yuengling, if that's all ya got.

Comment: @hvd Yep, thank you! We're currently poking at this to see what it'll take to get it fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback.  We have updated the wording to "willing to work in," which should better reflect the intended meaning.

[image: Updated "willing to work in" text]

Comment: Has this been reverted? My 'traditional view' currently has the wording 'Willing to relocate'...

Comment: @AakashM It's a different bug, actually -- the one I fixed was from before we launched Developer Story fully.  I will raise the issue with the team working on such things.

Comment: @AakashM The wording is now changed to "willing to work in" in the traditional view as well.